# Showing a Riemannian manifold is not complete

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> Let $M=(\mathbb{R}^n, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold equipped with the Riemannian metric $g= \psi g'$ where $g'$ is the standard Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\psi(x)=e^{x_n}$ for $x=(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $M$ is not complete.

I tried to use the Hopf–Rinow theorem and show that as a metric space $M$ is not complete, but I don't know how this should be done. When considering $M$ as a metric space we define $$d(p,q)=\inf_\gamma \ell(\gamma)$$ to be the metric where $\gamma$ is an admissible path from $p$ to $q$.

Now in order for this to not be a complete metric space one needs to find a Cauchy sequence in $M$ that does not converge. This isn't very clear to me how we should define these kinds of sequences and what would it mean to compute $d(p_n, p_m)$ say if the sequence is $(p_n)_n \in M$? Are we taking admissible paths between these points and trying to minimize the distance?

Comment: If $M$ is complete, as a metric space, one implication of Hopf-Rinow is that closed and bounded sets are compact. Try to find a subset of $M$ that is closed, bounded but non-compact.

Comment: Am I wrong thinking that the way that $g$ is given there should essentially be some kind of a "hole" in this space since the whole idea of completeness relies on being able to follow geodesics indefinitely? @Jonas

Comment: Note that the open upper half plane in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is incomplete.

Comment: We are dealing with the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not $\mathbb{R}^2$. @Deane

Comment: Louie, I believe that the point of Deane's remark was to give you an example where there are no holes in the space.

Comment: Write out the proof that the open half plane with the standard flat metric is incomplete and adapt it to your problem.

Comment: I don't know if that proof can be adapted to this. When proving that we take advantage of the space being the __open__ half-plane, but there isn't a way to adapt it here as we consider the whole space. @Deane

Comment: Have you followed my suggestion yet?

Comment: I tried, but as I said the incompletenss of the space you proposed follows from the fact that if we take any sequence $(x, 1/n) \to (x, 0)$, then this isn't in our space and so it's not complete with respect to the metric. Hopf-Rinow implies the incompleteness. I do not see how this could be used in the case I'm dealing with. @Deane

Comment: Try the sequence $(x,-n)$, $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Additional comment: For me the definition of a complete Riemannian manifold is that it is a complete metric space. A metric space is incomplete if there is a Cauchy sequence in the space that does not converge. The sequence I suggest above is such a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some geodesics in $M$ are easy to find almost without calculation. The maps ('reflections') $F_i:M\to M$,
$$F_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1}, -x_i, x_{i+1},\dots,x_n)$$
are isometries for $1\leq i\leq n-1$. Let us take a point $P\in M$ and a vector $v\in T_PM$ such that both $P$ and $v$ are fixed by all the $F_i$'s, e.g. $P=(0,\dots, 0)$ and $v=\partial_{x_n}$. Then the geodesics $\gamma$ given by $\gamma(0)=P$, $\gamma'(0)=v$ must be fixed by all the $F_i$'s, and so it is of the form $\gamma(t)=(0,\dots,0,f(t))$ for some function $f$ s.t. $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$. Finally, since for every $t$ we have $g(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))=g(v,v)=1$, we get
$$e^f (f')^2 =1,$$
therefore $f(t)=2\log(1+t/2)$. This geodesic is evidently incomplete.